# Detect if current script has been changed WITHOUT using subshell? (and start the new script)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, file, reload

is it possible to make a running script see if it has been changed/updated WITHOUT using a subshell command?

and if it has been updated, start the new script and kill the old one.

previously I used a separate file for it, so when I created the file, the script detected it. But if you're running multiply instances of the script this can be pretty messy

```
if [[ -f /mnt/g/update.tt ]]; then script.sh 2 && kill $$ ;fi
```

This function would be placed inside a loop that's taking about .8 second, that's why no subshell is important.

Comment: You can use `exec script.sh 2` to avoid the fork if that's what you mean

Comment: @oguzismail so what's -nt doing?, do you mean that this little code compares the script with the reference file to see if it's newer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best and easiest way to auto-update scripts is to compare the scripts modification stamp against an temporary file, which you create in the beginning of the script.

```
  scriptupdate=$(mktemp)
```

Just make sure you only run the **mktemp** once, and outside any loops, otherwise the script will update the control-file over and over again, making it newer than the script..

Then you just need to compare the script file with the temporary file to see if the script is never, then restart the script

```
if [[ $0 -nt $scriptupdate ]]; then
  exec $0 $@
fi
```

`Exec` replaces the running script with the new one
`$0` is the full path and name of the current script
`$@` passes along the arguments to the new run.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps:

```sh
age_of_script=$(( $(date +%s) - $(stat -c %Y "$0") ))
running_time=$SECONDS

if (( running_time > age_of_script )); then
    # script has been updated since I started running
    exec "$0" 2
fi
```

As `that other guy` commented, use [`exec`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-exec) to *replace* the current process.

---

With bash 4.3+, you may be able to use:

```sh
bash_root=${BASH%/bin/bash}
if [[ -d "$bash_root/lib/bash" ]]; then
  enable -f "$bash_root/lib/bash/finfo" finfo
  file_age() { echo $(( $(printf '%(%s)T' -1) - $(finfo -m "$1") )); }
else
  file_age() { echo $(( $(printf '%(%s)T' -1) - $(stat -c %Y "$1") )); }
fi
age_of_script=$(file_age "$0")
```

Still uses subshells for the command substitutions, but if your bash build has the loadable modules you may not need to use any external tools

---

For posterity, a quick benchmark for `stat` vs loadable `finfo`

```sh
$ file_age() { echo $(( $(printf '%(%s)T' -1) - $(stat -c %Y "$1") )); }
$ time for ((i=0; i<1000; i++)); do x=$(file_age /etc/hosts); done

real    0m14.750s
user    0m2.288s
sys     0m4.139s
```

```sh
$ file_age() { echo $(( $(printf '%(%s)T' -1) - $(finfo -m "$1") )); }
$ time for ((i=0; i<1000; i++)); do x=$(file_age /etc/hosts); done

real    0m7.162s
user    0m1.148s
sys     0m2.085s
```

Comment: but this one uses 2 subshells, is there no way to do this without it? subshells are so slow..

Comment: I don't think so. View this problem another way: if bash performance is a problem, it's time to use a different language for the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a reference file, then keep checking if the current script is newer than that reference:

```
#!/bin/bash
reference=$(mktemp)
thisscript="${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"
trap 'rm "$reference"' EXIT

printf '\nStarting\n'
while true
do
  if [[ "$thisscript" -nt "$reference" ]] 
  then
    rm "$reference"
    exec "$thisscript"
  fi
  printf "beep boop "
  read -t 0.8
done
```